# Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'selecao_artistas' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

for some reason I cannot seem to solve this bug. I am using Django 1.3.1

The actual error I get is:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'selecao_artistas' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My template:

```
{% if produto.artista %}
    {% if produto.artista.nome_artistico %}
        <h4><span>{% trans "Autor:"%} </span><a href="{% url selecao_artistas produto.artista.slug %}" >{{ produto.artista.nome_artistico }}</a></h4>
{% else %}
        <h4><span>{% trans "Autor:"%} </span><a href="{% url selecao_artistas produto.artista.slug %}" >{{ produto.artista }}</a></h4>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you post your urls.py?

Comment: too long by 10855 characters

Comment: Just the part with selecao_artistas

Comment: in fact this would be the error:

Comment: `Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'produtos_detalhes' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Comment: My Template

`<a href="{% url produtos_detalhes pp.slug %}" title=""><img src="{% thumbnail pp.get_foto 222x166 upscale %}" alt="" /></a>`

Comment: My urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('produtos.views',
url(r'^mais-recentes/$', 'mais_recentes', name="mais_desejados"),
url(r'^detalhes/(?P<slug_p>[\w_-]+)/$', 'detalhes', name="produtos_detalhes"),

Comment: Can you try with [-\w]* instead of [\w_-]+ ? I'm not quite sure about this, but it may help

Comment: it worked, stopped working alone :(

Comment: If it worked few times, then be sure that your pp.slug is not empty as  @user2734679 mentioned

Comment: you think pp.slug is empty?

Comment: yes, that can be the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you comment out your url tags, and just print out {{ produto.artista.slug }} and make sure it exists in that context. Because it looks like your passing in an empty argument, and your url patterns demand something to be there.

Note: I would leave this in a comment but my rep isn't high enough :(